# What would be the easiest way to lower the pr2's arms in gazebo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking through these tutorials: http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/

They are very helpful, but they seem to be broken with fuerte.  The arm navigation has trouble with the ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path service.

```
Motion planning service failed on /ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path
```

That's pretty much all you get besides more unsuccessful connection attempts.  That service also doesn't seem to be running, so I'm guessing it has been changed in fuerte.

What might be the necessary changes in order to get this to work with fuerte?  I'm hoping it is just changing the service name.

Most specifically this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmPoseGoalComplex

I'm attempting this in python right now, so this tutorial is the only one that translates well.  (there is no 'addGoalConstraintToMoveArmGoal' functionality in python)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40777/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-lower-the-pr2%27s-arms-in-gazebo?/) by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I love this answers site, I spend all day working on something, give up, ask a question, and then 2 minutes later I find the answer: http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter18#Tucking_PR2_Arms

Looking at the python file is very helpful for understanding basic arm movements

---

Originally posted by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) with karma: 120 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1